# Gedmo and parent select in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've implemented Gedmo nested trees in my Symfony2 project and I'm trying to build a parent select. I read the doc https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md
 but it's very short note about this kind of issues.

I can't get an array of nodes with a identation based on node levels.

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('SymdruMenuBundle:MenuLink');
$options = array(
    'decorate' => true,
    'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
        return str_repeat('&nbsp;', $node['lvl']).'-'.$node['title'].'</a>';
    },
    'html' => false,
);
$htmlTree = $repo->childrenHierarchy(
    null, /* starting from root nodes */
    false, /* true: load all children, false: only direct */
    $options
);

var_dump($htmlTree);

$form->add('parent', 'choice', array('choices' => $htmlTree));
```

It gives me a string instead of an array.

I can do it like this

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$links = $em->getRepository('SymdruMenuBundle:MenuLink')->findAll();

$choices = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $choices[$link->getId()] = str_repeat('--', $link->getLvl()).$link->getTitle();
}
```

but is this the best way?

The second issue here is how to get a parent object when I save the children to the database?